# Python more elegant way to write this IF OR statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a more elegant way to write this statement? I find myself writing ones similar quite a lot.

```
if ('.jpg' in imagename[0].lower() or '.png' in imagename[0].lower() or '.jpeg' 
    in imagename[0].lower()):
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want

```
if imagename[0].lower().endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png")):
    # whatever
```

Note that `str.endswith()` accepts a tuple of strings.  Also note that this code is not equivalent to yours, since it only checks for the mentioned strings at the *end* of the filename, but chances are that this is your intention.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
if any(ext in imagename[0].lower() for ext in ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg']):
```

`any(boolean_list)` returns `True` if `boolean_list` contains a `True` element.

Answer (score 0):

One other method (for fun):

```
if imagename[0].lower().split('.')[-1] in ('jpg','png','jpeg'):
    # do something
```